# (JavaScript) Syntax rules

Tags: javascript

While I study codes from a textbook, I saw the following code;

```
   if (isNaN(investment) || investment <= 0 || investment > 100000){
      error = "Investment must be a number greater than zero"
            + " and less than or equal to 100,000";
   }
```

Here, why do we need plus sign here? I know we use + and " " becuase it is string but I want to know if there any special reason for it. If I were the writer, I would have wrriten like this (I mean without + sign) "Investment must be a number greater than zero and less than equal to 100,000";

Comment: it was done to break it into two lines. Especially important when formatting a text book. But many coding guidelines insist on a max line length as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to keep the code readable without horizontal scrolling. Compare to, without concatenation:

```
   if (isNaN(investment) || investment <= 0 || investment > 100000){
      error = "Investment must be a number greater than zero and less than it equal to 100,000 and maybe some other stuff";
   }
```

It doesn't look so good - you can't read the entire text without scrolling horizontally (and would probably violate the [`max-len`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len) linting rule as well).

Code is usually most readable when there are no areas which require horizontal scrolling.

Even if a long line doesn't result in horizontal scrolling, unnecessarily long lines can still be difficult to read. For similar reasons, newspapers often have long, thin columns, rather than wide columns.